# Date error on StackExchange site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange-2.0, timestamps

This StackExchange question is displaying strange dates:

[Why does a company pay dividends at all?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/619/why-does-a-company-pay-dividends-at-all)

[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]
[image: Example3]

All of the date seem to be set to December of 2009, but this is a new-ish StackExchange site.

It's possible that I'm missing something (migrated question? but from where?) but wanted to flag this as a bug just in case there is some datetime wierdness in the SOflow sequels.

Comment: My suspicion is that this is imported data from an old SE 1.0 site. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: I asked the same thing here: http://stackapps.com/questions/1309/api-money-stackexchange-com-returning-questions-from-2009

Answer (score 3):

This site imported the old SE 1.0 basicallymoney.com data.